# Using SQL within attributes

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to do some calculations with a field and select the value. In my attributes I have:

```
attributes: ['username', 'last_activity', '(last_activity - 1000) as test']
```

That doesn't work, since it encloses the SQL in quotes.

How can I do something like this with Sequelize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With v2.0.0dev12 you can do:

```
Model.find({
  attributes: [
    'username', 
    'last_activity',
    // (last_activity - 1000) as test
    Sequelize.literal('(last_activity - 1000) as test')
    // (last_activity - 1000) as `test` - the as part is quoted
    [Sequelize.literal('(last_activity - 1000)'), 'test']
  ]
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll upgrade to v2.